# Unit test service call

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, proxy

I'm trying to unit test code surrounding a service call - i want to test that

```
1. the client.retrieveDetails call is made, 
2. the client.retrieveDetails call is made with the correct request and 
3. the result contains an error code and an exception is thrown if it matches a specific one.
```

I have the following method in a class, it contains other operations as well. I need to instantiate the proxy in each method call (MyClient), so i cannot have one instance of it at class level. How can I unit test this method?

```
    public virtual List<Detail> GetDetails(long code)
    {
        detail_Type[] details;

            var client = new MyClient();
            var context = ContextV2();
            var result = client.retrieveDetails(
                    ref context,
                    IdentifierV2(code),
                    out details);

            _exceptionGenerator.ThrowExceptionIfCodeIncorrect("" + result.resultCode, result.resultMessage);
        }

        List<Detail> response = Mapper.Map<detail_Type[], List<Detail>>(details);

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. the client.retrieveDetails call is made
> 2. the client.retrieveDetails call is made with the correct request and

You can create a wrapper around your service and use a mock. If you use a mock framework like [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), it is pretty easy to check for a method call.

> 3. the result contains an error code and an exception is thrown if it matches a specific one.

For this, I would create separate tests, which only tests the behaviour of the service implementation.

Comment: Yes, i would like to mock it out, but how would creating a wrapper around the service help? I need to test the method and the client is instantiated in that method

Comment: If you create the service instance in a method you want to test, then this method isn't testable. You need to create an instance outside of the class you want to test. Then, in productive environment you instantiate your real wrapper implementation, and your unit tests will instantiate a mock. `GetDetails` only knows the interface of your wrapper.

Comment: Look for **Dependency Injection** or have a look at [this](http://jumping-duck.com/tutorial/dependency-injection-interfaces-c-sharp/) example. Now I think there is need for another layer. Because your WCF service already implements an interface. You can inject and mock this interface.